# Memory Overflow for Custom ImageView

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiimageview, out-of-memory, nsobject

I have an object which is a subclass of a UIImageView that checks for a specific image on another object. If there's a image, the ImageView displays it, otherwise it displays a temporary image while it downloads a new one. After the download is completed, the ImageView  displays the new Image. this object I called "Imager".

I instantiate a Imager on cells in a tableview.
For some reason, the imager is overflowing the memory of my app. Before the implementation of the Imager, the memory usage of the app used to be around 60Mb, but after its implementation it goes to 300Mb, so I receive memory warnings and the iPhone closes the app, just as expected.

I want to know, what am I doing wrong? It's not a complex code or logic, but definitely I'm doing something thats raising the memory. I would guess is the table view, but I'm not sure.

Heres the code for the Imager:
Imager.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "friend.h"
#import "Group.h"
#import "Mimo.h"
@interface Imager : UIImageView
-(void)loadFriendImage:(friend*)theFriend;
-(void)loadGroupImage:(Group*)group;
@end
```

Imager.m

```
#import "Imager.h"
#import "Group.h"
@implementation Imager

-(void)loadFriendImage:(friend*)theFriend{
    if(!theFriend.flagDownloaded){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(theFriend.userImg == nil)
                    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image@2x.png"]];
                else{
                    [self setImage:theFriend.userImg];
                }
            });
            NSLog(@"[IMAGER]: Will load %@ image.",theFriend.username);
        UIImage *friendImage = [theFriend downloadImageBlocked];
        if(friendImage != nil){
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self setImage:friendImage];
            });
        }


        });
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"[IMAGER]: %@ image already exists",theFriend.username);
        if(self.image == nil)
            [self setImage:theFriend.userImg];
    }

}
-(void)loadGroupImage:(Group*)group
{
    if(!group.flagDownloaded){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image@2x.png"]];
            });
            NSLog(@"[IMAGER]: Will load %@ image.",group.groupName);
            UIImage *groupImage = [group downloadImageBlocked];
            if(groupImage != nil){
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self setImage:groupImage];
                });
            }


        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self setImage:group.groupImage];
    }
}
```

this is the table that uses the Imager objects

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Imager *accessory;
    friend *workingFriend = [thisUser.friendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = workingFriend.username;
    //----------------Setup Accessory View-----------------------------------

                    accessory = [[Imager alloc]init];
                    [accessory loadFriendImage:[thisUser.friendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                    accessory.frame = CGRectMake(cell.accessoryView.frame.origin.x, cell.accessoryView.frame.origin.y, 72.0, 72.0);
                    accessory.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                    accessory.clipsToBounds = YES;



                    cell.accessoryView = accessory;

                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17]];
                    //----------------------------------------------------------
  return cell;
}
```

this is the Download Image Blocked function that downloads the image

```
-(UIImage*)downloadImageBlocked
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tatohouston.azurewebsites.net/getUserImg.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
    NSDictionary *tempDic;

    //---------------------------------
    tempDic = @{@"userid":userID};
    //serialize the dictionary data as json
    NSData *dataPost = [[tempDic copy] JSONValue];
    [request setHTTPBody:dataPost]; //set the data as the post body

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)dataPost.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSData *tmpData = [[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(tmpData != nil){
        returnData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedData:tmpData options:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    UIImage *friendImage;

    if(returnData != nil){
        friendImage = [UIImage imageWithData:returnData];
        userImg = friendImage;
        flagDownloaded = YES;
    }
    return friendImage;
}
```

Comment: Use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Mark Generation (Heapshot) in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: Minor suggestion: friendInage should be set to nil when you create the variable otherwise this code could cause bugs when it returns some other random pointer if returnData happens to be nil.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the NSData being returned from the request? I see that it is using Base64 encoded data which is 1.37x larger than unencoded generally speaking. My guess is that your image data is quite large.

Comment: The NSData from the request is around 121894 bytes, do you think it might be that? Usually there are less then 10 rows that loads these data.

Comment: Profile your app for memory allocations and determine exactly what seems to be taking up all that memory and report back as @Zaph suggested above. That should help point you in the right direction.